# Firefox repeats setup every time I restart it. -- tiresome

Tags: firefox

Every time I reboot or otherwise need to restart Firefox, it complains that it cannot use an old profile, and insists I create a new one.  It gets old bookmarks from Chrome, but of course that misses any that I created the last time.  Each time I have to resinstall any addons that I use.

I'm currently on Xubuntu 20.04.5 and Firefox 106.0.2

How can I fix this?

Comment: More information is needed. What are the permissions on your profile directory?

Comment: For everything I can see under ~/.mozilla, directories are 700, .ini files are 664.  And I have to say I never looked into these before, but there are a lot more of them than I expected, with names like nqh7viro.default-release-1 through qvhaks06.default-release-7.

Comment: Hmmm.  There are 21644 lines of output to "ls -ltR .mozilla/firefox"  --  I have to say I'm inclined to delete the whole thing and see if it can start over.  Or uninstall and reinstall.  Or both.

Comment: 700 is correct for the profile folder, so that's not it.

Comment: Use `about:profiles` to see available profiles and what the default profile is.

Comment: @user3169 Thanks.  Although it seemed cryptic at first, this contained the clue that will let me set this right -- I found my old profiles and I can move them to a machine that has not been recently updated.  There I can access bookmarks and my extensions -- the very large lists that I was afraid were lost.   Then I expect to abandon Firefox forever -- that is not excusable behaviour.